# Scala Convert Set to Map

Tags: scala, scala-collections

How do I convert a Set("a","b","c") to a Map("a"->1,"b"->2,"c"->3)?
I think it should work with toMap.

Comment: Do you want b to map to 2 because it's the second in the Set? Or becasue it's the second letter in the alphabet? Sets aren't ordered, as other posters have pointed out, so the first won't work.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`zipWithIndex` is probably what you are looking for.  It will take your collection of letters and make a new collection of Tuples, matching value with position in the collection. You have an extra requirement though - it looks like your positions start with 1, rather than 0, so you'll need to transform those Tuples:

```
Set("a","b","c")
  .zipWithIndex    //(a,0), (b,1), (c,2)
  .map{case(v,i) => (v, i+1)}  //increment each of those indexes
  .toMap //toMap does work for a collection of Tuples
```

One extra consideration - Sets don't preserve position.  Consider using a structure like List if you want the above position to consistently work.

Answer (score 19):

Here is another solution that uses a [`Stream`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream$.html) of all natural numbers beginning from 1 to be zipped with your `Set`:

```
scala> Set("a", "b", "c") zip Stream.from(1) toMap
Map((a,1), (b,2), (c,3))
```

Answer (score 7):

`toMap` only works if the `Set` entries are key/value pairs (e.g. `Set(("a",1),("b",2),("c",3))`).

To get what you want, use `zipWithIndex`:

```
Set("a","b","c") zipWithIndex
// Set[(String, Int)] = Set((a,0), (b,1), (c,2))
```

or (as in you original question):

```
Set("a","b","c") zip (1 to 3) toMap
```

Answer (score 3):

This would also work:

```
(('a' to 'c') zip (1 to 3)).toMap
```